# Is it possible to have DbContext in DAL in layered ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, ef-core-2.1

For example, if I have 3 layers:

```
Data access layer -> Business Logic Layer -> Presentation Layer
```

is it possible to have a `DbContext` in the DAL considering I can't reference it from the presentation layer?

If yes, so how can I initialize using DB in `Startup.cs` if I won't able to see `DbContext`?

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                {
                    ...
                });
```

Comment: if the presentation layer is the composition root why can't you reference the context?

Comment: You could always expose some form of configuration that bubbles up through another layer to be invoked at the composition root. It does not necessarily have to expose the DbContext but it will need to be able to access the service collection in order to be able to add configure it.

Comment: If you add DAL project reference to Presentation layer, you could reference `DbContext`, share us the reason you can't reference from Presentation layer.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you probably provide a small example with bubling configuration? Can't understand how it will looks like.

Comment: The `DbContext` basically is your DAL.  If your app references the BLL which references the DAL then your app will indirectly reference the DAL and `DbContext` will be very much available in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: @Brad and how can I specify a connection string in DAL if I don't have IConfiguration there?

Comment: @Pyrejkee just like I suggested with the service collection, you would need to pass it (`IConfiguration`) down as well.

Comment: @Nkosi I've posted an answer, considering you suggestion, actually it works fine for me. Could you take a look?

Comment: @Pyrejkee yep that answer is what I was referring to. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found such kind of solution of my problem(Considering guys helped me in comments)
I have a static class with extension method for `IServiceCollection`

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterRepositories(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(DbContext), typeof(NorthwindContext));
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

        return services;
    }
```

I have approximately the same but for BLL

```
public static class ServiceCollectionsExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterBllServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.RegisterRepositories(configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And in Presentation Layer in `Startup.cs` I have something like this

```
services.RegisterBllServices(_configuration);
```

So now Presentation Layers doesn't know anything about `DbContext` and what `ORM` I'm using